# What approach do you take for embedding links in flash messages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionpack

The ability to have flash messages (notice, error, warning, etc) with embedded links is nice from a user interaction standpoint.  However, embedding an anchor tag inside a flash message from the controller is dirty.

Let's assume that a flash message like this is good for usability*:

[Example Flash Message Notice with an Embedded Link http://img.skitch.com/20090826-xbsa4tb3sjq4fig9nmatakthx3.png](http://img.skitch.com/20090826-xbsa4tb3sjq4fig9nmatakthx3.png)
*(borrowed from [DailyMile.com](http://dailymile.com))*

**What tactic would you take between the controller and view to employ something like this cleanly?**

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just thought I would share this, since found answer I was looking for elsewhere:

Works on rails 3.1

```
flash[:notice] = "Proceed to #{view_context.link_to('login page', login_path)}".html_safe
```

Comment: Making this as the new accepted answer. This is much more clear than the approach I was taking before. I wasn't aware of the `view_context` accessor.

Comment: view_context works in all Rails 3 versions. It's been introduced in 3.0.0 according to http://apidock.com/rails/AbstractController/Rendering/view_context

Answer (score 8):

[Glenn Gillen](http://glenngillen.com/) has an approach that he calls [Useful Flash Messages in Rails](http://rubypond.com/articles/2008/07/11/useful-flash-messages-in-rails/).

I modified his code snippets to be a little more idiomatic (for me at least).

The controller fills the flash like this:

```
flash[:notice]      = "Your profile was updated. %s"
flash[:notice_item] = ["Edit again?", edit_profile_path(@profile)]
```

You then might have helpers that look something like this:

```
def render_flash_messages(*keys)
  messages = keys.collect do |key|
    content_tag(:p, flash_message_with_item(key), :class => "flash #{key}") if flash[key]
  end.join
  content_tag(:div, messages, :id => "flash_messages") unless messages.blank?
end

def flash_message_with_item(key)
  item = flash["#{key}_item".to_sym]
  substitution = item.is_a?(Array) ? link_to(*item) : item
  flash[key] % substitution
end
```

The view looks simply like this:

```
<%= render_flash_messages(:error, :notice, :warning) %>
```

The view (via the `flash_message_with_item` helper) is responsible for creating the anchor tag, but the controller manages what goes into the flash message including an optional resource for further action.

Comment: I was hoping for some more savvy suggestions, but I'll go with this approach for now.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a helper method to render out partials based on the value passed back in the flash message.

Comment: This almost feels like too much separation.  Also where do you manage which object or path should be linked to without relying on global-like instance variables within the partials?