# Flash and rails with HTML

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I'm trying to put a simple smiley into a flash message like so:

```
flash[:info] = "Please check your email to activate your account &#9786;"
```

from the controller

```
if @user.save      
   flash[:info] = "Please check your email to activate your account &#9786;"
```

How do I get ruby to execute this code, it worked right then as I typed the question, but on my rails app not so lucky. I am rendering my flash as a partial on the **application.html.haml** page that simply loops through  the flash messages and displays the message.

**_flash.html.haml**:

```
-flash.each do |message_type, message|
    =content_tag(:div, message, class: "alert alert-#{message_type}")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sanitize()` to render html entity instead of escaping it:

```
=content_tag(:div, sanitize(message), class: "alert alert-#{message_type}", escape: false)
```

Comment: That looks like a view rendering to me

Comment: @SpencerHire: Well, in your view, sanitize your output (where you display your flash messages).

Comment: Thanks but, adding sanitize(render 'layouts/flash') in application.html.haml doesn't help.

Comment: @SpencerHire: not like this, exactly in the `layouts/flash` file, where you output you messages.

Comment: Yah, tried that in the flash partial also, no luck.

Comment: @SpencerHire: you are doing it wrong, just post your `layouts/flash` file in the question.

Comment: @SpencerHire: What is your rails version by the way?

Comment: Ok no worries, version = 4.2.0

Comment: Thanks that worked :-), you wouldn't happen to know how to interploate link_to's into flash also?

Comment: @SpencerHire: You are welcome, for your question have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1598590/3444240)